# WatchConnectivity not activating on iOS side when running on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, session, watchconnectivity

I am trying to run my project on Simulator but the iOS side does not activate and only the Watch side manages to activate.

Here is my ScoresInterfaceController.swift (Watch side)

```
import WatchConnectivity    

class ScoresInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    // Used to send information to the iOS app
    var applicationDict = [String: Int]()

    // Starts a session to communicate with the iOS app
    var session: WCSession!

    // For WCSession
    override init() {
        super.init()

        if(WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession,
             activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState,
             error: Error?) {}
```

Here is my ScoreViewController.swift (iOS side)

```
import WatchConnectivity    

class ScoreViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {    

    // Starts a session to communicate with the Watch app
    var session: WCSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if(WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()    //Not activating when run on Simulator      
        }
    }

    // For WCSession

    /** Called when the session has completed activation. If session state is WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated there will be an error with more details. */
    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {}

    // Receives data from Watch app
    @nonobjc func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {}

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {}

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        WCSession.default().activate()
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

[image]

I followed this tutorial but I cannot figure out what the issue is:

http://kristina.io/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my ScoreViewController's definition of session from this:

```
@nonobjc func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {}
```

to this:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any])
```